# hql removes parentheses from parameter value

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, hql

I have a hql request where I have to filter rows by parameter value from list. 
I pass parameters to request and everything works fine till one of parameters not contains parentheses.
If parameter = 'Windows' everything ok, but if 'macOS 10.13 (High Sierra)' it not founds proper rows.

```
select agent where agent.operatingSystem in (:p1,:p2)
```

I found that if rows with filtering value without parentheses exist - it query founds them: 
this query return agents with os = "macOS 10.13 High Sierra" but not found "macOS 10.13 (High Sierra)"

Comment: Can you post the actual query code?

Comment: something like:  select a where a.os in ('windows', 'macOS 10.13 (High Sierra)')

Comment: select agent where agent.operatingSystem in (:p1,:p2)

Comment: do **not** add code in comments. [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. Prepare you list of Operating Systems and pass it as list to your "in clause".

```
Query query = session.createQuery("FROM YourTable t WHERE t.os IN (:osIds)");
query.setParameterList("osIds", listOfOs);
```

Comment: It not helps. 
But I found that if rows with filtering value without parentheses exist - it query found them